# Perl XML-RPC over HTTPS

Tags: perl, ssl, xml-rpc

I have several Perl scripts that utilize DBI that I am cleaning up and converting into Rose::DB.  My company uses a product called Password Manager Pro (PMP) for managing authentication resources.  PMP has an [XML-RPC API](http://www.manageengine.com/products/passwordmanagerpro/help/a-to-a-web-service-api-xml-rpc.html#pmp.password.retrieve) and I am trying to build a module that Rose::DB::Object will call to obtain a password for a database resource rather than the credentials being stored as clear text.

I've looked at [RPC::XML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?RPC%3a%3aXML) and [XML::RPC](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aRPC) and can find no option for ssl.  I've googled for an example of XML-RPC over HTTPS but have had no luck.

Most of my scripting has been database related, I haven't done much with web based modules as of yet.  I was hoping someone could recommend a solution/example as to how I can pass the following XML to a server and identify myself with an SSL cert:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<methodCall>
  <methodName>pmp.password.retrieve</methodName>
    <params>
      <param>
        <value><string>pmp-server</string></value>
      </param>
      <param>
        <value><string>administrator</string></value>
      </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

I started my module with the following, but without ssl being presented to the server its no good:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use XML::RPC;
my $certfile = /home/api/.ssl/pmp.p12;  #Where to pass this?
my $xmlrpc = XML::RPC->new('https://pmp.local:7070/xmlrpc');
my @result = $xmlrpc->call( 'pmp.password.retrieve', {
   resourceName => 'DBSERV', 
   userAccount => 'APITest', 
   reason => 'Test' 
});

print @result;
```

Any suggestions help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, though probably not the best, is to use an SSL proxy like [stunnel](http://stunnel.org/).  You set it up to listen on a port and any connections that come in are forwarded to another address/port using the appropriate certificate.  It's one more moving part, which is less than ideal, but it does get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

XML::RPC use LWP first(if he installed), LWP for SSL use Crypt::SSLeay and Net::SSL, they use this variables:

```
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE}     = 'certs/pkcs12.pkcs12';
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD} = 'PKCS12_PASSWORD';
```

UPD: all keys if needed.

```
# proxy support
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY} = 'http://proxy_hostname_or_ip:port';

# proxy_basic_auth
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY_USERNAME} = 'username';
$ENV{HTTPS_PROXY_PASSWORD} = 'password';

# debugging (SSL diagnostics)
$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;

# default ssl version
$ENV{HTTPS_VERSION} = '3';

# client certificate support
$ENV{HTTPS_CERT_FILE} = 'certs/notacacert.pem';
$ENV{HTTPS_KEY_FILE}  = 'certs/notacakeynopass.pem';

# CA cert peer verification
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_FILE}   = 'certs/ca-bundle.crt';
$ENV{HTTPS_CA_DIR}    = 'certs/';

# Client PKCS12 cert support
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE}     = 'certs/pkcs12.pkcs12';
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD} = 'PKCS12_PASSWORD';
```